# "Database" files are overriden in Heroku

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I am trying to avoid using a DB in my simple RESTful app.
I created a "posts.txt" file which has all the posts in it, the app reads from this file and creates the posts array (JSON.parse).
The problem is, when I "git push heroku master" it, the "posts.txt" in heroku gets overriden and thus I lose all the posts created by guests.
I tried to .gitignor this file but it seems I just do it worng (or that I didn't understand the idea of "untracking" a file).
What can I do in order to prevent the overriding (I just don't want to push a new "posts.txt" into heroku every time)?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid a database?

Comment: This site will be visited very rarely, using a DB just seems like a waste if I can only write the posts info into a text file and then read from it (when the server is restarted).

Comment: Makes sense, but just because a site is visited rarely doesn't decrease the need for a quality site, correct? I mean if you want it to work and be functional the way you are describing, you need a DB layer. Doesn't mean the DB layer has to be overly complex. Just needs to get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to your Heroku app potentially being run on multiple servers over time, there is no way to ensure that your `posts.txt` file will remain consistent overtime. Also as you make changes, and as you have noted, it can easily get overwritten.

Heroku can terminate your application and start it on another server as needed. Almost like a server-less type setup.

That means there is no real way to ensure a stable data persistence on Heroku without some type of database layer.

---

Great point mentioned in the comments that I forgot to mention. The file will also be deleted after cycling because the filesystem is ephemeral. You can find more information about file uploads missing/deleted on Heroku's site [here](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted).

---

One other thing about this is even you are using some type of VPS or something like that, you'd still run into the problem of how to sync the posts down to your local machine during development and ensuring that stays in sync.  Database layer is for sure the way to go here.

Comment: Not only will it not be consistent, but the file will also be deleted after cycling because the filesystem is ephemeral. More on that [here](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted).

Comment: yes, I just read about it 5 mins ago...
I was sure that the posts.txt file was overriden by the fact that I was pushing git into heroku, but now I understood that I was wrong (I even wrote "heroku restart" in the console and saw that the posts.txt "reverted" to it's initial value).
Thanks, for your help guys.